# Windows 10 version 1809 will not update to 1903 or 1909 automatically

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-v1809, windows-10-v1909

I have a Windows 10 Pro v1809, OS build 17763.1339. According to the MS docs, this is the latest update to version 1809.
I'm not sure why feature updates are not being shown via Windows update. I have not disabled/ paused updates. I don't see the option to select "Choose when updates are installed" from Windows Update > Advanced Options. Instead I had to manual set those from the Group Policy editor.

Is there a way to trigger feature updates automatically without doing a clean OS install?

[image]

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Use the Media Creation Link (first option on that page) and see if you can make it update. Caution:  This will take you to V2004.  You can try clicking on Windows Update and see if you can kick off updates this way. But you do have updates turned on, so I am not sure this will do more.

Comment: Google "Windows 10 Update Assistant" download it from Microsoft and run it, see if it offers an upgrade.

Comment: Yes, I tried doing that at first. The Windows 10 Update Assistant only tries to install v2004 and that apparently fails due to some compatibility issues. The error logs are not clear which program/ driver, but I'm guessing it has to do with answer https://superuser.com/questions/1389692/windows-10-update-1809-not-offered-even-if-i-manually-search-for-it

Comment: Download 1909 ISO, mount within Windows, run setup.exe and the upgrade will proceed.  I suspect you had deferred feature updates at some point.  I recognize a problem with the deferrement options not being there

Comment: I can almost guarantee you my answer to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1506475/windows-10-1903-missing-deferment-feature-and-quality-update-option) will explain the reason you haven’t received a required feature update in over a year.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, it didn't work. Tried setting both DeferFeatureUpdatesPeriodInDays and DeferQualityUpdatesPeriodInDays to 0 and restarted. The options are still missing. I had set the deferment days to 0 using the group policy editor since it didn't show up in the default location. Yet, the feature updates didn't trigger automatically. Will try to get the 1909 version iso file from a trusted source and try the other solution.

Comment: Consider yourself lucky. 1903 and later only bring annoyances and more bugs than they fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution as suggested in the comments!

Download the preferred version using the TechBench link and install while logged in. You should be able to perform the upgrade manually, without a clean install.
Please note that your version is up-to-date before upgrading to next version.
Eg: If you are trying to move from version 1809 to 1909, make sure your currently at version 1809 build 17763.1339, the latest as of today. I had trouble when my build was not up-to-date. Check version history [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/)).

Downloads for previous versions are available here (TechBench by WZT): https://tb.rg-adguard.net/public.php

Note: The download link merely provides an interface to download from official Microsoft servers. These files are legit. Do check the checksum for good measure before install. Also, answered [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/179331/is-downloading-windows-isos-from-techbench-downloaders-safe?newreg=466ec5caff5e4e808ba50a68f3a82fb7).

Comment: If it _provides an interface to download from official Microsoft servers_, would you be able to share a link to the Microsoft servers directly please?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to @pateksan since I cannot comment, you can navigate to the correct links from here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/release-information

You can look through this page to find exact versions of Windows 10 to download from the Microsoft Catalog.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).